# Qual a diferença entre "decimal.Divide" e o tradicional "/" em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, decimal

```
decimal a = 10/5;
```

Retorna 2

```
decimal b = decimal.Divide(10,5);
```

Retorna 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Nenhuma** prática, é só uma forma sintática diferente, eles executam exatamente a mesma coisa. Pelo menos se estivermos falando só desse exemplo específico ou de uso com decimais.

Veja o [fonte do operador](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Decimal.cs,970). [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.op_division?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). [No .NET Core mudou um pouco](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Decimal.cs,1b2858baf311cbf9) mas ainda é igual ao operador nesta plataforma.

```
    public static Decimal operator /(Decimal d1, Decimal d2) {
        FCallDivide (ref d1, ref d2);
        return d1;
    }
```

Código IL gerado usando o operador:

```
.maxstack  4
.locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal V_0)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::x
IL_0006:  ldsfld     int32 Program::y
IL_000b:  div
IL_000c:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Implicit(int32)
IL_0011:  stloc.0
IL_0012:  ldstr      "{0} / {1} = {2}"
IL_0017:  ldsfld     int32 Program::x
IL_001c:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0021:  ldsfld     int32 Program::y
IL_0026:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_002b:  ldloc.0
IL_002c:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_0031:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                            object,
                                                            object,
                                                            object)
IL_0036:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_003b:  nop
IL_003c:  call       void Program::Teste()
IL_0041:  nop
IL_0042:  ret
```

Agora vamos usar valores decimais como operandos:

```
.maxstack  4
.locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal V_0)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::x
IL_0006:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::y
IL_000b:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Division(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                              valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_0010:  stloc.0
IL_0011:  ldstr      "{0} / {1} = {2}"
IL_0016:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::x
IL_001b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_0020:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::y
IL_0025:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_002a:  ldloc.0
IL_002b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_0030:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                            object,
                                                            object,
                                                            object)
IL_0035:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_003a:  nop
IL_003b:  call       void Program::Teste()
IL_0040:  nop
IL_0041:  ret
```

Veja o [fonte do método](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Decimal.cs,387). [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.divide?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_Divide_System_Decimal_System_Decimal_)

```
    public static Decimal Divide(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
    {
        FCallDivide (ref d1, ref d2);
        return d1;
    }
```

Código IL gerado:

```
.maxstack  4
.locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal V_0)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::x
IL_0006:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Implicit(int32)
IL_000b:  ldsfld     int32 Program::y
IL_0010:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Implicit(int32)
IL_0015:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::Divide(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                         valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_001a:  stloc.0
IL_001b:  ldstr      "{0} Divide {1} = {2}"
IL_0020:  ldsfld     int32 Program::x
IL_0025:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_002a:  ldsfld     int32 Program::y
IL_002f:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0034:  ldloc.0
IL_0035:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_003a:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                            object,
                                                            object,
                                                            object)
IL_003f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0044:  nop
IL_0045:  ret
```

Agora vamos usar valores decimais como operandos:

```
.maxstack  4
.locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal V_0)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::x
IL_0006:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::y
IL_000b:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::Divide(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                         valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_0010:  stloc.0
IL_0011:  ldstr      "{0} Divide {1} = {2}"
IL_0016:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::x
IL_001b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_0020:  ldsfld     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::y
IL_0025:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_002a:  ldloc.0
IL_002b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Decimal
IL_0030:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                            object,
                                                            object,
                                                            object)
IL_0035:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_003a:  nop
IL_003b:  ret
```

Note que ambos são métodos estáticos (mesmo que um seja sintaticamente um operador). Ambos aceitam sobrecarga, mas estes não possuem. Nenhum aceita sobrescrita. Ambos tem os mesmos parâmetros, e o mesmo retorno. Ambos usam o mesmo sistema de *upcast* implícito nos parâmetros/operandos, afinal o *cast* é uma operação independente. Então a promoção de outros tipos ocorrem em ambos. Eles geram as mesmas exceções.

Dá para notar que acaba sendo o mesmo. O compilador otimiza ambos para o mesmo código.

Obviamente usei variáveis que o compilador não consegue otimizar para simular o uso real. Com literais pode gerar código diferente por alguma deficiência do compilador que eu não saberia explicar. O uso de variáveis é o caso comum. Fazer testes sem contexto pode ser complicado. No afã de evitar contaminar o objeto de teste com outros efeitos, muitas vezes comparamos coisas que realmente não aconteceria no uso em código real.

Veja [o código usado no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OC4v8L). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RCr2RI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/MethodVsOperator.cs).

## Há diferenças

Há diferença no código gerado entre o operador e o método. Também há diferença quando os argumentos são do tipo decimal e não inteiros.

Percebe-se que com inteiro a divisão é feita de forma nativa (usará instruções do processador para inteiros) e depois ocorrerá uma promoção de tipo com o resultado. Com a divisão a promoção ocorre já com os argumentos do método.

Com o uso de argumentos decimais não há promoção e dá para notar que dois métodos são chamados, um fazendo as vezes do operador (`op_Division()`) e o outro é o óbvio.

Justamente por essa diferença, os resultados podem ser diferentes quando a divisão não é exata quando usado valores inteiros. O mesmo não acontece quando os [valores são decimais](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l2BPkU). Um dos motivos para se usar o método é garantir que a promoção ocorra. Claro que isto é possível fazer com o operador. Aí tem que ser explícito:

```
decimal a = (decimal)10 / (decimal)5;
```

Aí o IL fica o mesmo que a divisão feita só com decimais.

## Conclusão

Se a dúvida é só sobre a diferença entre usar o operador ou o método, que foi minha primeira interpretação, a diferença é puramente sintática.

Se a intenção da pergunta é considerar o que acontece no caso dos operandos serem inteiros, aí há um diferença fundamental no resultado (valor encontrado e performance que pode não ser tão negligenciável assim), já que é uma operação totalmente diferente que será executada.

Se a intenção era comparar estes códigos exatos, o primeiro está fazendo uma divisão de inteiros e promovendo o resultado para decimal e o segundo faz promoção de inteiros para decimais e faz uma divisão de decimais.

Comment: Pra quem for pensar em negativar, eu tentei fundamentar o melhor que deu. A minha resposta é oposta à outra existente. Obviamente uma das duas está errada. Eu confio na minha, mas se alguém conseguir mostrar algum erro, eu gostaria de aprender o certo.

Answer (score 7):

As respostas de Maniero e de Cigano Morrison Mendez estão corretas, apontando as diferenças de métodos para operadores. Mas neste exemplo específico, não há diferença alguma (*) - as variáveis `a` e `b` terão o valor 2 (decimal). Como o valor foi calculado é que é um pouco diferente.

No primeiro caso (`decimal a = 10/5;`), os valores **inteiros** 10 e 5 são divididos, resultando no valor **inteiro** 2. Esse valor é, em seguida, convertido para o tipo decimal, e atribuído à variável `a`.

No segundo caso (`decimal b = decimal.Divide(10,5);`), os valores inteiros 10 e 5 são convertidos para o tipo **decimal**, e depois o método `decimal.Divide` é chamado, com o valor de retorno 2 (**decimal**) é atribuído à variável `b` (**).

Ou seja, os dois métodos levaram caminhos diferentes para chegar ao mesmo resultado. Se você tivesse dois inteiros cuja divisão não fosse exata (e.g., `decimal c = 10 / 3;`), o resultado seria diferente.

(*) Ok, tecnicamente há uma diferença, mas ela não afeta o resultado; se tiver alguma diferença de performance ela será negligível.

(**) Na verdade, se você tiver usando as constantes `10` e `5` no primeiro caso, o compilador provavelmente será esperto o suficiente e efetuar aquela operação diretamente, e aquela operação será equivalente a `decimal a = 2;`.

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu melhorei a minha baseado no que colocou.

Answer (score 4):

[`/` é um operador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx). [`Decimal.Divide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.decimal.divide(v=vs.110).aspx) um método.

- Um operador aceita sobrecarga; um método aceita polimorfismo. Os conceitos são diferentes;
- Um operador tem diversos tipos de retorno; um método tem alguns, dependendo da assinatura do método usada. No caso da sua operação, os números não são exatamente decimais. Podem ser inteiros, mas o compilador infere que são decimais pela sua declaração;
- Ainda que o retorno seja o mesmo, `Decimal.Divide` é uma forma muito mais restritiva (e, portanto, mais adequada à tipagem forte) que o operador de divisão, que precisa intuir o tipo de retorno de acordo com os operadores.